# Ruby: parsing over a csv file and expecting some text

Tags: ruby, csv, rspec

I have some logs that need analyzing to check if the logs do not have abnormalities and are incorrect form so to speak.

I have generated a CSV file for it:

```
"timestamp","source","message
"2021-10-18T09:12:29.000Z","Storage","Storage apache: [18/Oct/2021:09:12:29 +0800] 10.102.141.82 - GET /deviceManager/rest/
"2021-10-18T09:12:29.000Z","Storage","Storage apache: [18/Oct/2021:09:12:29 +0800] 10.102.141.82 - GET /deviceManager/rest/
"2021-10-18T09:12:29.000Z","Storage","Storage apache: [18/Oct/2021:09:12:29 +0800] 10.102.141.82 - GET /deviceManager/rest/
"2021-10-18T09:12:29.000Z","Storage","Storage apache: [18/Oct/2021:09:12:29 +0800] 10.102.141.82 - GET /deviceManager/rest/
```

I use the CSV gem to parse/read this file and use an RSpec test to expect some value/text/time format etc. I have written the code below. It takes the rows from 8 to 12 for example and I want to expect a text called "Huawei" f.e in those rows.

```
    RSpec.describe "Log parsing" do
    it 'returns the source' do
      table = CSV.read("Messages_result.csv")
      puts arr = table.values_at(8..12)
      arr.each do |rows|
         expect(rows).to include('Huawei')
      end
    end
end
```

The problem I am getting is it always executes the expect for the first line but I want to parse/iterate through the whole CSV file and should as well show me for each line a result. My expect message will change of course but I just want to check first for a basic text like Huawei. Can somebody please show what I am doing wrong since each do should theoretically go through the complete rows and throw an expectation for each?

Comment: Your CSV is truncated, please add the missing end of lines

Comment: is there a chance `arr` is empty?  put a check before `expect(arr).not_to be_empty`

Comment: Is there a reason why you only select the lines 8 to 12 of the CSV file (considering that the header is line 0)? Also, you're loading the whole CSV file into memory while you only to check it line by line.

Comment: @Anthony not its not empty i get 
       expected ["2021-10-18T09:11:24.000Z", "Storage", "Storage apache: [18/Oct/2021:09:11:24 +0800] 10.102.141.82 -.../license/feature HTTP/1.1 python-requests/2.21.0 - - application/json - */* gzip, deflate 200 49 0"] to include
"Huawei" so it definitely gave me an error for the first element

Comment: @Fravadona its just to test out my code for some elements before i go through the whole csv file which is like 500 lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i want to parse/iterate through the whole csv file and should as well show me for each line a result.

That's not possible, see [Add a configuration option to continue on failure](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues/2510).

That said, by modifying a little the code, you can make Rspec check the whole file and *display* all the rows that fail your `expect`:

```rb
RSpec.describe "Log parsing" do
  CSV.foreach("Messages_result.csv", :headers => true) do |row|
    it 'returns the source' do
      expect(row.to_h.values).to include("Huawei")
    end
  end
end
```

outputs:

```
FF

Failures:

  1) Log parsing returns the source
     Failure/Error: expect(row.to_h.values).to include("Huawei")
       expected ["2021-10-18T09:10:29.000Z", "Storage", "Storage apache: [18/Oct/2021:09:10:29 +0800] 10.102.141.82 - GET /deviceManager/rest/"] to include "Huawei"
     # ./Messages_result.rb:10:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'

  2) Log parsing returns the source
     Failure/Error: expect(row.to_h.values).to include("Huawei")
       expected ["2021-10-18T09:11:24.000Z", "Storage", "Storage apache: [18/Oct/2021:09:11:24 +0800] 10.102.141.82 -...../license/feature HTTP/1.1 python-requests/2.21.0 - - application/json - / gzip, deflate 200 49 0"] to include "Huawei"
     # ./Messages_result.rb:10:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'

  3) ...
```

If you really want to display a message for each line of the CSV then you don't have any other choice than print it yourself. For example:

```rb
# get the output stream that Rspec is currently using
ostream = RSpec.configure { |c| c.output_stream }

# define a few colorization helpers
if ostream.tty?
  def red str; "\e[31m#{str}\e[0m"; end
  def green str; "\e[32m#{str}\e[0m"; end
else
  def red str; str; end
  def green str; str; end
end

RSpec.describe "Log parsing" do
  it 'returns the source' do
    ostream.puts
    ostream.puts "  -) Log parsing returns the source - details"
    expected = "Huawei"
    success = true
    CSV.foreach("Messages_result.csv", :headers => true) do |row|
      values = row.to_h.values
      detail = "expected #{values} to include #{expected.inspect}"
      ostream.print ' ' * 5
      if values.include?(expected)
        ostream.puts green("PASSED: #{detail}")
      else
        ostream.puts red("FAILED: #{detail}")
        success = false
      end
    end
    ostream.puts
    ostream.flush
    expect(success).to be(true)
  end
end
```

Comment: i have tried this already and it generates the same result.

Comment: @Khan_saab check my updated answer.

Comment: thanks alot for your help :) these work great. No i dont intend to use it as a logger just parse it

Comment: @khan_saab You're welcome ;-). BTW, you can `accept` my answer if it's what you where looking for ;-)

Comment: ohh sorry, new here :D  thanks again :)

Comment: i have a question to ask since i realized that code outputs for the rows , what if i wanted to do for only the headers for example whatever comes under "timestamp" and i would like to make an expect for them. is it possible ?

Comment: @khan_saab You can refer to the current value of the column `timestamp` with `row["timestamp"]`